# In Excel, How do I trap a mouse click in a specific cell to activate a macro?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a Excel macro that does a simple sort. I want the end-user to be able to click on a specific call and initiate the macro. I need to trap the mouse-click to respond on it.

Answer (score 1):

#### To prompt the user to click a range

You want to use an [inputbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839468(v=office.15).aspx)

```
Set myRange = Application.InputBox(prompt := "Sample", type := 8)
```

#### To start a macro when a cell is selected

Or, if that's not what you meant and you meant activate the macro on the click you need a [worksheet_change event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775(v=office.15).aspx)

This goes on the sheet's VBA in the VBE. Something like

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target as Range)
if not intersect(target,range("A1")) is nothing then
 'call macro
end if
End sub
```

#### Other Ways

You can also put a button or control into your sheet that triggers a macro to begin when it is clicked. Take a look at the microsoft [KB](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/add-a-button-and-assign-a-macro-to-it-in-a-worksheet-HP010236676.aspx)